# InkCanvas to 2-D Array in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I want to convert all the `Strokes` in my `InkCanvas` to 2-dimensional array. It would need to be the same size as `InkCanvas` is, but filled with information about each pixel(or just boolean value that informs if that pixel was written on) that is present in it. Is there such an option available inside .NET, or do I have to write it by myself? Also if there is not, I would appreciate some tips.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.strokes.aspx), the `InkCanvas` class has a `Strokes` property that stores a collection of strokes. You could turn these into a list or array like this:

```
var listOfStrokes = new List<Stroke>();
foreach(var s in myInkCanvas.Strokes)
    listOfStrokes.Add(s);
var arrayOfStrokes = listOfStrokes.ToArray();
```